# Cannot get 2nd vlan to access internet or ping router gateway

Tags: switch, router, vlan, sonicwall, ping

I have an existing data network of 192.168.1.0/24 consisting of a switch and SonicWall TZ200. I am adding an Avaya switch for their new phone system. I created 2 vlans on the new switch - one for their existing data network and a second for the phone subnet 192.168.2.0/24. I can ping back and forth across the switch all day, but I can't get my phone system controller at 192.168.2.30 to ping 192.168.1.1 (default gateway of the router.) I have static route on switch 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 1 but still nothing. Switch is live in production - waiting to put phone system live when I can get this. Phone system has to access internet time server. Any help??

Comment: Is your Avaya switch a Layer 3 switch?

Comment: Can you provide a basic diagram showing the nodes, and how you believe routing should be functioning between the phone system controller and 192.168.1.1? Based on the information you provided, I would begin by ensuring the phone system controller is configured with a default gateway IP address capable of routing the traffic to the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

Comment: And is routing *enabled* on it?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean to say that the router has an IP address 192.168.1.1/24, and this is the default gateway for clients in subnet 192.168.1.0/24? The router has another default route pointing to somewhere in the Internet.

Think of a subnet as a house, and gateway as a door. To get into or out of the house you must use the door of that house, neighbor's door just won't do. The same way to get into or out of subnet 192.168.2.0/24 your SonicWall must have an IP address on this range. This is the IP interface it will use to route traffic into and out of this subnet.

So basically you must create the Avaya VLAN in your SonicWall and give it an IP address 192.168.2.1/24. This is the IP you use as default gateway for devices in the Avaya VLAN. Then you tag the link between the switch and the SonicWall to the Avaya VLAN, and traffic should flow correctly.

You should be able to do this configuration in a live production network without causing any disruption in the network services.

Comment: I like the gateway/door example ^^